# How to get all draft message with specific label attached to it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gmail-api

I have written a script, where I want to pull all draft message whose tag is `shc`.

**Code:**

```
function getDraftsWithLabel_shc() {
 Logger.clear();
 Logger.log("fn start..");
 var drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages(); //getUserLabelByName(ulables[x].getName()).

 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("shc");
     Logger.log(label);
     var threads = label.getThreads();
     Logger.log("LBL NAME ="+label.getName());
     Logger.log("THREAD ="+threads.length);

 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

       var message=threads[i].getMessages();
       Logger.log(" thread ID = "+threads[i].getId());

       if(message.length<0)
       {
           for(m=0;m<message.length;m++){
              var isD=message[m].isDraft();
              Logger.log("is Draft ="+isD);
              if(isD)
              {
                    Logger.log(message[m].getSubject()+" = "+message[m].getTo()+" = "+message[m].getDate());
              }
           }
       } 
       else 
       {
           Logger.log("No mesage");
       }
 } 
   Logger.log("fn Ends..");

}
```

Here in code i am trying to get the labelname and then respective threads. Then loop over thread and by using `getMessages()` check for if current `isDraft` then based on conditon get all other details.

First I am not able to get messages. Second is there any efficient way to get direct all Draft threads with specific labels coz looping over all thread is taking so much time

---

**Screenshot of Log:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`drafts.list()` now accepts raw query param `q` so you can simply specify it to do what you want. Something like:

```
q=in:<label>
```

---

See Gmail API's [`Users.drafts: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list#parameters) docs for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Google do all the heavy lifting for you by going straight to listing messages, and explicitly saying that you want messages with your label `shc` and that they should be `drafts`.

```
query = is:draft AND in:shc

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=is%3Adraft+AND+in%3Ashc&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to do that in your framework. You know that better than me!

### Edit 1

As Eric pointed out, this will give you the messageId of all the drafts you are interested in, but not the draftId. <strike>Drafts.list() does however not support a custom query. Bummer.</strike>

One solution would be to list all the relevant drafts as above, and in parallel get all of your drafts as well. After both requests are answered, you can figure out what messageIds overlap. The messages with overlapping messageIds has the `draftIds` you are looking for. (If you don't care about the draftIds, the solution above will suffice of course)

### Edit 2

The Drafts.list() now supports a `q`-parameter:

**Request**

```
q = is:draft AND in:STARRED

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?q=is%3Adraft+AND+in%3ASTARRED&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "drafts": [
  {
   "id": "1540187177260115336",
   "message": {
    "id": "155fd813d4336588",
    "threadId": "155fd813d4336588"
   }
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Comment: **+1** thank you so much for your reply, your answer gave me a new direction to think, by using `.search(QUERY)` I get the result. But am not sure about whether is right way ( performance wise). am not marked as answer , still waiting for some more answers  :)

Comment: @Satindersingh No problem! Yeah, let's see what the others will say :) I'm pretty certain this is the way to go, since it's only one request instead of many, and Google has to do the work for you!

Comment: messages.list() will give you them but only the message IDs, not also a draft ID.  so once you know the message IDs you won't be able to call any of the drafts.*() methods.

Comment: @EricDeFriez Ah, good point. And drafts.list() does not support a query. Shoot.